# How to get the count of items in pandas dataframe that are not unique and by row?

Tags: python, pandas

Most solutions I find are to get the count of unique items (which I don't want) in a dataframe, or counting by columns with clear headers.

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
       1   2   3   4
ILLU1 ATG --T --- TGG
ILLU2 ATG -CT GGG TGG
ILLU3 ATG TTT AAA TGG
ILLU4 -TG --T --- T-G
```

I am trying to get a count per row where each column has a complete 3-base sequence. So if "-" is present in the cell, it would be a zero (this includes "---", "--N", "-NN").

So I am trying to make the output as follows:

```
ILLU1 2
ILLU2 3
ILLU3 4
ILLU4 0
```

I have tried:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame() # to hold the final values
count = 0
for rows in df:
   if not sum(df[rows].str.contains("-")) > 0: # if no hyphen present
       count += 1 # add to final count
   else:
       count = count # does not get included final count
       df_new["Final Count"] = count 

print(df_new)
```

But I just get an empty dataframe with no values.

Answer (score 5):

Using `str.contains`

```
s=(~df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('-'))).sum(1)
s
Out[384]: 
ILLU1    2
ILLU2    3
ILLU3    4
ILLU4    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What does the "~" symbol mean here?

Comment: @DNAngel change False to True , True to False

Comment: Omg I never knew that, what a useful tidbit! I will give this a shot and let you know thank you!

Comment: @DNAngel yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ['-' not in i for i in x]).sum(1)
```

OR

```
df.apply(lambda x: ['-' in i for i in x]).ne(1).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
ILLU1    2
ILLU2    3
ILLU3    4
ILLU4    0
dtype: int64
```